# SQL Server administrator needs to be able to assign new users to roles on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

we have following requirement for SQL Server:
SQL Server administrator needs to be able to assign new users to roles on SQL Server. Create an account that allows this security function and only this function.

Kindly help for SQL Server command to implement this requirement.

Best Regards

Comment: Double click on a role, add users. This is described in the online documentation, with detailed UI *and* script steps. You can also click on the `Scrip` icon at the top of the dialog's toolbar to generate the scripts the dialog would execute

Comment: This sounds like a quiz / homework question. The permissions for functions are documented - have a [look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). And note that the word "administrator" can be easily confused or mis-interpreted. Here it seems you just need to given a "person" (login? database user?) the appropriate permissions. Similarly, "create an account" is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Create a stored proc which does the needed things, sign it with certificate, grant dedicated account to run the proc.

https://sqlundercover.com/2018/05/02/digitally-signing-a-stored-procedure-to-allow-it-to-run-with-elevated-permissions/

Comment: This is the correct real-world answer to providing limited admin ability to a user.  Granting role memberships and permissions is fraught with escalation-of-privilege risks unless you're very careful, and even then it's tricky to _prove_ that no escalation-of-privilege risk exists.

Answer (score 1):

If this was a question on a interview or certification exam, and assuming that by "user" they mean "database user" (and not "login"), I believe the answer they are looking for is that the user should be granted the ALTER ANY ROLE database permission.

This permission allows the user to run [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to add or remove database users from custom database roles.